# How can I make a peach material similar to this picture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Do you have any idea how to make a peach material like in the picture? So that it is also a bit shiny and that it also becomes darker at the bottom just as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The darker gradient is just a shadow. What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? :)

Comment: I know but I want to have this shadow as default. I tried to recreate this shadow with layer weight and a coloramp but I never get the right result I want.

Comment: Do you want material shadeless - so this shading will be independent on lights and other objects in a scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Switch Color Management from Filmic to Standard
- The rest seems to get Color Ramp
- Colors I grabbed by picker directly from your screen

[image]

... or you can let contribute also Ambient Occlusion.

[image]

[image]